# How is it specified what is the first page to show in this Spring MVC demo application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studtyin for the Spring Core certification and I have a doubt related Spring MVC use.

I have a demo webapp. When I run it on TomCat server it is automatically open this URL into the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/mvc/
```

that show a web page.

Reading on the course slides it say that:

> Once deployed, navigate to the index page at
>   http://localhost:8080/mvc. You should see the index page display

Ok, I can't find no information about a main page that have to be open as entry point of my webapp but I find the **index.html** file into the folder: **/mvc/src/main/webapp/index.html**

So my doubt is: the **webap** folder is a folder that could contains my views (the other jsp views of the webapp are into some subdirectory into this folder) and so if I put here an **index.html** file it is open by default at the startup of the web application without that I need to specify a welcome file or something like this?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welcome file mechanism is specified in the [servlet specifications](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340) (section 10.10 of the servlet 3.0 version). It doesn't have much to do with Spring.

In the case of Tomcat, if you don't specify any welcome file in your webapp's descriptor, the default configuration (present in tomcat's conf/web.xml file) is used instead. And it contains

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

which means that Tomcat will use these 3 files as welcome file.

Comment: Ok, this is clear now but this is a specific TomCat feature or it is valid for all the application server\servlet container?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for default welcome files, although I'd expect for index.html to be a default everywhere in practice. But if it's important for your app, and you expect to deploy it on many servers, then specify the welcome files in your web.xml: that is standard, specified in the spec, and every compliant server must thus respect it.

Answer (score 0):

in your web.xml file there is an entry named :

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

there you can define your own starting point.